# While loop that updates and uses back the updated value, Python

Tags: python, while-loop, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Trying to write a while-loop function that could update the content within itself for a sparse matrix calculation:

I have some brief chunk of codes, but it was wrong as it will return me the same value regardless of my t, I believe it's an error in my while loop, appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

```
HS = [[1,1],[1,0]]
HS = sparse.csr_matrix(HS)
initial_PS = [[0.5],[0.5]]
initial_PS = sparse.csr_matrix(initial_PS)

t = 1
r = initial_PS

while (t < 10):

  # r(t+1) = HS * r(t)
  r = HS * r
  
  print(r)

  t = t+1
```

Comment: You can't multiply lists. what do you expect `HS * r` to return?

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop for this. Use `for t in range(1, 10):`

Comment: Aren't you getting an error from the line `r = HS * r`?

Comment: `r(t+1)` is wrong. Parentheses are for calling functions. Indexing is done with square brackets.

Comment: What does this have to do with sparse matrixes?

Comment: @Barmar, this is for a bigger function, with 10000 rows & cols, filled with mainly 0's and some occasional 1's. I am expecting a (2x1) matrix of (1, 0.5). Then this (1, 0.5) will be the new r used in r = HR * r (now 1, 0.5). For some reason r  = HS * r does run, but it always return the same result regardless of my t (I believe the r value didn't get updated), how can I use t in range (1,10)? I only need the last result from the loop. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't have `sparse.csr_matrix()` in the code when I asked the above questions. I thought you were multiplying lists.